# Using cgroups to limit CPU and I/O by process name under CentOS7 / systemd

Tags: centos7, systemd

I am currently using cgroups (via `/sbin/cgrulesengd`) on CentOS 6 to limit CPU usage for processes with process names `zip`, `unzip` and `gpg`.

I'm achieving this via this in `/etc/cgconfig.conf` to define some control groups...

```
group limitcpu {
        cpu {
                cpu.shares=256;
        }
}

group limitio {
        blkio {
                blkio.throttle.read_bps_device = "9:1         5292880";
                blkio.throttle.write_bps_device = "9:1        5292880";
        }
}
```

... and this in `/etc/cgrules.conf` to then place processes in those groups:

```
*:zip           cpu,blkio       limitio/,limitcpu/
*:unzip         cpu,blkio       limitio/,limitcpu/
*:gpg           cpu,blkio       limitio/,limitcpu/
```

I am wanting to now reproduce the same setup on CentOS 7. The CentOS 7 documentation says that this way of doing things is deprecated (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/chap-using_libcgroup_tools). Under CentOS 7, it seems that you should use facilities from systemd (https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/resource_management_guide/chap-using_control_groups).

My problem is that the documentation (and other resources in Google) do not make clear how to achieve my aim. They mostly concentrate on limiting systemd *services* or processes that you control the launching of.

However, in my setup, users run the mentioned binaries via a variety of means (some indirectly via other tools they are using), and I specifically want to limit binaries run that way (i.e. politely asking users to modify the commands they are running is not a solution).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think for this you’d need to write a service which keeps watching for new `zip`/`unzip`/`gpg` processes, and moves them to a dedicated slice (or scope) as soon as they appear (write their PID to e. g. `/sys/fs/cgroup/limitZUG.slice/cgroup.procs`, assuming cgroups v2). That seems to be mostly what `cgrulesengd` does in your current setup (though I’m not familiar with it), except that the cgroup it moves the processes to would be set up by systemd as a slice unit (or a scope unit dynamically created by the service).

(I also thought about overriding `zip`/`unzip`/`gpg` into wrappers around `systemd-run -p CPUShares=256 … /usr/bin/…` via scripts in `/usr/local/bin/`, but that means you need to give unprivileged users the ability to create new system services with `systemd-run`, because resource control doesn’t seem to be available in user units: the user manager lacks permission to set it up, I think.)

Comment: `cgrulesengd` - https://linux.die.net/man/8/cgrulesengd - does basically that (moves things into their own group). What I haven't understood is why Red Hat consider it deprecated, if there's not yet something else that can do the same thing. (For things that aren't services, that is).

Answer (score 0):

The systemd implementation (at least in Ubuntu-land) isn't mature yet. (In other words, ignore the deprecated thing and keep doing what you were doing in CentOS 6)